# How to get the index of an sorted array where the summary of first n values larger than a certain value

Tags: python, numpy

if I got a sorted numpy array A=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], I want to get the index where the sum of A[0: index] that bigger than a certain number (supposed to be 9, in this case, the value of index should be 3), how can I write it in python?

I think maybe I can use np.where() or np.cumsum() but it doesn't work

```
np.argwhere(np.cumsum(A) > 9)
```

of course, it is wrong, so what is the correct method?

Comment: Use `argmax` - `(np.cumsum(A)>9).argmax()`.

Comment: Do you want one index satisfying the condition or all of them?

Answer (score 0):

You were close. You can just use `argmax` as follows. Also, when using argmax, add a check to ensure that atleast 1 value crosses the threshold.

```
threshold = 9
temp = np.cumsum(A) > threshold

if temp.any():
    print(np.argmax(temp))
else:
    print("Threshold never crossed")
```

Comment: This is assuming there is at least one index satisfying the condition. You might want to add a conditional check on that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
def foo(array, threshold):
    valid_entries = np.cumsum(array) > threshold
    return np.argmax(valid_entries) if np.any(valid_entries) else None
```